# Filtering data in dict

Tags: python, pandas

I am fetching following data via my broker's API call:

```
{'1': [{'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43214', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700', 'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20700 CE ', 'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'CE'}, {'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43218', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20700', 'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20700 PE ', 'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'PE'}, {'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43206', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20600', 'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20600 CE ', 'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'CE'}, {'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43207', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20600', 'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20600 PE ', 'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'PE'}]}
```

Its type is `<class 'dict'>` and `len(my_dict)` returns `1`.

I want to specifically fetch key:value pairs from this dict, for instance `'token': '43214'` and `'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20700'`, and put them in a separate new dict where corresponding `token('43214'):tysm('NIFTY07DEC23P20700')` becomes key:value pair, how can I do this?

```
new dict - {'43214':'NIFTY07DEC23C20700', '43218':'NIFTY07DEC23P20700', '43206': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20600', '43207': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20600'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a dictionary from those two parts of each element of the list if dictionaries in the first dictionary item:

```
dct = {d['token']:d['tsym'] for d in my_dict['1']}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten all nested dictionaries to one final dict:

```
out = {x['token']:x['tsym'] for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
print (out)
{'43214': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700', 
 '43218': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20700', 
 '43206': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20600',
 '43207': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20600'}
```

Or for each outer dictionary create list of dictionaries:

```
out = [{x['token']:x['tsym'] for x in v}  for k, v in d.items()]
print (out)

[{'43214': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700', 
  '43218': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20700', 
  '43206': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20600', 
  '43207': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20600'}]
```

If outer dictionary has multiple values output is:

```
d = {'1': [{'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43214', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700',
            'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20700 CE ',
            'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 
            'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'CE'}, 
           {'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43218', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20700',
            'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20700 PE ', 
            'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 
            'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'PE'}, 
           {'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43206', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20600',
            'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20600 CE ', 
            'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 
            'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'CE'}, 
           {'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43207', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20600', 
            'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20600 PE ', 
            'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 
            'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'PE'}],
     '2': [{'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43211', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700',
            'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20700 CE ',
            'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 
            'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'CE'}, 
           {'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '43218', 'tsym': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20700',
            'weekly': 'W1', 'dname': 'NIFTY 07DEC23 20700 PE ', 
            'instname': 'OPTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 
            'ti': '0.05', 'optt': 'PE'}]}
```

---

Output is dictionary, but with unique keys, so one `token='43218'` is removed:

```
out = {x['token']:x['tsym'] for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
print (out)
{'43214': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700', 
 '43218': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20700', 
 '43206': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20600', 
 '43207': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20600', 
 '43211': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700'}
```

Output is list of dictionaries:

```
out = [{x['token']:x['tsym'] for x in v}  for k, v in d.items()]
print (out)
[{'43214': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700',
  '43218': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20700',
  '43206': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20600',
  '43207': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20600'},
 {'43211': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700', 
  '43218': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20700'}]
```